# How bad are 3 degrees Celsius for a lithium battery and electronics?

Tags: power-electronics, temperature, batteries, lithium

I have a PCB powered by a [lithium battery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FPpz.jpg) , it works well inside the house, but when I leave it exposed to low temperatures with humidity the PCB or the battery stops working.
I leave the PCB in the backyard "garden"of the house inside a [waterproof box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIFSh.jpg)  where temperatures at this time reach perfectly 1 degree celsius, it works correctly until to become night, when the temperature drops.

Could it be that the humidity, the low temperatures are causing the electronics to fail? (Only one day it showed signs of oxidation, despite being protected by the box)

[this is the evidence of oxidation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaQLs.jpg)

Comment: put a heat source inside that box, to avoid condensation.

Comment: whats , are you kidding me

Comment: Nope, he's not. Thermally insulate the box excellently. Put a heating resistor and a temperature control circuit in there. It doesn't have to heat the inside to 40°C. 15°C is sufficient.

Comment: it is a IoT experiment  maybe it is not good idea a heating resistor :( because battery life

Comment: Another idea is assembling the box on a harsh dry and very cold day, put silica gel in, then seal it.

Comment: Okay I will try thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly is this device?  What sort of current draw does it have versus time, ie what is the average and what is peak?  Many battery types do poorly in cool temperatures, LiPo cells such as yours can see their peak current performance seriously reduced.  It may be that something like some disposable alkaline flashlight batteries would solve your practical problem.  Also do not overlook the possibility of software bugs causing failure when the temperature goes negative!  Fortunately most of us have a handy subzero test chamber that usually leaks enough RF for a signal to get out...

Comment: mmm my last test I use a lipo battery 3.7v 18650 and step up module adjustable to 5V. In the night my PCB died because the step up failed and no regulation to 5V. I was getting sometime 8 volts :( I dont like low temperature in garden test

Answer (score 0):

To prevent condensation the components in the cabinet should be above the [dew point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dew_point).
There are two ways to do that:

- Reduce the relative humidity, for example with silica gel.
- Increase the temperature, with a heater.

---

When cold the chemistry in the battery slows down. Which increases the internal resistance of the battery, reducing it's effective capacity. Refer to the battery datasheet to view how much you lose.